# How to make a wavy, symmetric circle in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, geometry, shader, webgl, trigonometry

I'm trying to develop a shader where I can modulate the the number of curves on a circle, but I'm having an issue in that it is not symmetric. That is, while I can increase the waviness of the circle, it appears as if all waves come from a point on the left-hand-side.

There's a [shader here](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/fljBzw) which demonstrates this effect perfectly.

If you click on the ShaderToy link above, you'll notice that the it appears that all the additional curves come from the origin (0 degrees). That is, the left side moves a lot, and the right side of the circle hardly moves at all.

Is there any way to modify this effect such that the curves are more symmetrical in their generation? Ideally it wouldn't look like the curves are originating from the left-hand side, but rather appear in a more uniform manner.

Shader code copied below in case you cannot access the ShaderToy link:

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;
    uv = uv * 2.0 - 1.0;
    uv.x *= iResolution.x / iResolution.y;

    float l = length(uv);
    float thi = atan(uv.y,uv.x);

    float freq = sin(iTime) * 9.5 + 5.0;
    float sina = sin(floor(freq) * thi);
    float sinb = sin(ceil(freq) * thi);
    float fr = fract(freq);

    float r = 0.5 + 0.05 * mix(sina, sinb, fr);
    //float r = 0.5 + 0.05 * sin(freq * thi);
    l = step(l,r);
    vec3 col = vec3(0.0,0.5,0.8);
    fragColor = vec4(col*l,1.0);
}
```

**Edit:** Oops, I didn't realize the shader link was set to private! Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this approach is that for each integer frequency the zero point will always be peak on the sin wave. So that place that shares those peaks will appear to not change.

You have to pick some point to consider the "zero" angle. But you can vary where that is so the peaks don't noticeably stack up on each other.

I've abstracted an example of that to this function:

```
float ripples(float thi, float freq) {
    float adjustedThi = thi + freq;
    // causes each frequency to have it's zero peak at a different spot.

    return sin(floor(freq) * adjustedThi);
}
```

This makes it a bit more organic.

See: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/NtSBWz

Comment: The shader is private so I cannot view it unfortunately. Can you make it public?

Comment: @RyanPeschel whoops try now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can remove time and give it a fixed frequency, and just mix them with base.
`r = mix(0.5, r, abs(sin(iTime)));`

Or make it even to get symmetry.

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/sljBzm

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Remove time? But your answer uses time? Could you perhaps link me an updated ShaderToy with what you mean? I tried adding that line you pasted to line 17 on mine, but it didn't seem to have much of an effect.

Comment: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/sljBzm

Comment: I think you have to make it public. Because I cannot view your link at the moment.

Comment: Sorry. You can check again.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the link. Unfortunately this seems to just vary the strength of the individual waves. What I'm looking for is a way to transition from having, say, 3 waves, to, say, 7 waves, without it looking like they're all originating from the left hand side origin. If you take a look at the original shader in my post you should be able to see what I'm talking about. Notice how in that shader the number of waves changes over time, but they all originate from the left-hand side.

Comment: I find it hard to conceptualize a solution in my mind because it sounds paradoxical. I updated it with one of the ways I could think of.